# Gradle Tab not Showing in android studio 3.0

Tags: gradle, tabs, android-gradle-plugin, runtime, gradle-plugin

The Gradle Terminal (also called Gradle Command Line) is not showing in my android studio 3.0,  I have been searching for how to view the terminal for over an hour now and all I get is tutorials about how to use it and not how to show it so I can eventually use it. Anybody got a solution for this? thanks in advace..
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCECd.jpg

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/FW0Dv

Comment: Did you have it in previous version of AS? As I know, AS has usual Terminal (it is in the first place in your screenshot in the bottom panel) where you can use gradle commands as usual (depending on your OS and system variables it can be "gradle dependencies" or using wrapper: "./gradlew dependencies"). In addition, there is a Gradle tools panel and it is in the right part (vertical panel) in your screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be as simple as just right-clicking the build.gradle file in the file listing, and then choose "Import Gradle"